# Determine CPU frequency from command line

Tags: bash, shell, cygwin, performance-testing

I have a Bash script that detects CPU frequency from the command line and then calls the benchmark suit for a C/C++ library. Here's the essence of the script:

```
# CPU frequency in GHz
CPU_FREQ=2.0
if [ "$IS_LINUX" -ne "0" ] && [ -e "/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/cpuinfo_max_freq" ]; then
    CPU_FREQ=$(cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/cpuinfo_max_freq)
    CPU_FREQ=$(awk "BEGIN {print $CPU_FREQ/1024/1024}")
elif [ "$IS_DARWIN" -ne "0" ]; then
    CPU_FREQ=$(sysctl -a 2>/dev/null | $GREP 'hw.cpufrequency' | head -1 | awk '{print $3}')
    CPU_FREQ=$(awk "BEGIN {print $CPU_FREQ/1024/1024/1024}")
elif [ "$IS_SOLARIS" -ne "0" ]; then
    CPU_FREQ=$(psrinfo -v 2>/dev/null | $GREP 'MHz' | head -1 | nawk '{print $6}')
    CPU_FREQ=$(nawk "BEGIN {print $CPU_FREQ/1024}")
fi
```

It just occurred to me the script is failing under Cygwin and Cygwin-64.

How do I determine CPU frequency in the script under Cygwin and Cygwin-64?

Comment: Please speak up if you feel this belongs on Super User rather than Stack Overflow. I think it can go either way, but I'd be happy to flag it and asked it be moved.

Comment: at least you have some good code. My inclination is to keep it here. `cygwin` may rely on a Windows utility to produce that level of info BUT I think getting linux-like packages is pretty easy, so you might luck out  (but I haven't used cgywin in a long time, so this is just my barely informed opinion ;-) ) . Good luck!

Comment: My favorite place to go reading about Open Dev projects is nabble.com . Maybe you can find your topic allready discussed by searching http://cygwin.1069669.n5.nabble.com/ . Good luck!

Comment: Funny that nobody ask why you are dividing by 1024... :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

`grep 'cpu MHz' /proc/cpuinfo | head -1 | awk -F: '{print $2/1024}'`

(when I run this in my cygwin terminal I get 1.85156).

Comment: Cygwin does have `/proc/cpuinfo` actually.

Comment: I see what I did wrong... I turned to `/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/cpuinfo_max_freq` for frequency because it appears to be more accurate. It turns out Cygwin and Linux kernels 2.6, 3.1 (and probably more) are missing the `cpufreq` subtree. When my program reported a default value, I [incorrectly] assumed it was because `/proc/cpuinfo` was missing.

Comment: I think the line with 'cpu MHz' is actually the current frequency (on chips that scale), so it can vary.  You may need to grep the "model name" line for max cpu frequency, but parsing that cross-platform may be involved.

Comment: Using `cpu MHz` is horrible (no offense to the answer). ARM64 Mustang board is missing all frequency information. ARM64 HiKey is missing all freq information. ARM CubieTruck5 reports in *inaccurate* BogoMIPS. ARM BeagleBone reports in BogoMIPS. Now I remember why I used `/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/cpuinfo_max_freq`...

Answer (score 0):

You can use `dmidecode -t 4` to view your basic CPU information and this should be accurate as it is querying the BIOS/EFI directly rather than through OS indirections. It doesn't capture the current frequency (for CPUs that support C-States or P-States), but an application like i7z may be better suited for that scenario.

Comment: Thanks @dragon. Its an unprivileged script, and it results in *`/dev/mem: Permission denied`*.